# How do I (safely) kill long running operations in MongoDB?

Tags: replication, mongodb

Occasionally operations get out of control in MongoDB and might end up running for hundreds of seconds, and impact performance until they are killed or completed.

When that happens, I know I have [`killOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) available to me but how do I kill only targeted long running operations without also killing (for example) the long running operations involved in replication (which can be dangerous)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be a little tricky, but the fact that the MongoDB shell is basically a Javascript interpreter gives us decent options in terms of filtering.  Here is the function I use to accomplish this:

```
// kills long running ops in MongoDB (taking seconds as an arg to define "long")
// attempts to be a bit safer than killing all by excluding replication related operations
// and only targeting queries as opposed to commands etc.
killLongRunningOps = function(maxSecsRunning) {
    currOp = db.currentOp();
    for (oper in currOp.inprog) {
        op = currOp.inprog[oper-0];
        if (op.secs_running > maxSecsRunning && op.op == "query" && !op.ns.startsWith("local")) {
            print("Killing opId: " + op.opid
            + " running over for secs: "
            + op.secs_running);
            db.killOp(op.opid);
        }
    }
};
```

This will only kill queries above the `maxSecsRunning` threshold and will not touch anything running against the `local` database, which is where the `oplog` lives (and hence is the database that is involved in the long running replication ops.  It is relatively easy to add criteria to the inner `if` conditional to more precisely target operations as needed based on specific needs.

The code is also available as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/comerford/9248866) (where I will remember to update it on an ongoing basis).

Comment: I've seen several scripts for this one. Nevertheless, to check if the operation is running against the local database is a nice improvement.

Comment: yeah - I have given this out numerous times, and saw a blog post with a very dangerous script for killing ops, so thought I would give myself a nice and easily linkable version

Comment: I believe this is a dangerous script at least when using replicasets.  Running `db.currentOp()` on our sharded database returns operations in the "" namespace (aka ns: "") that are very long running with a desc of "repl writer worker n" (where n is an integer). I would suggest whitelisting the namespaces to your actual databases with queries that you may want to kill. Something like `&& (['users', 'analytics'].indexOf(op.ns) != -1)` instead of the `!op.ns.startsWith` condition.

Comment: Good point, and it's entirely possible that the blank namespace happens more frequently in newer versions - I originally intended to keep the script up to date, but I have now left MongoDB, so that is unlikely I am afraid.  If you submit your updated code (with a note that it applies to later versions) here as an answer I will happily vote you up :)